# fast string check looking for in-string duplicates

Tags: c#, php, javascript, regex

A `string = "aabbccaaabbcbbdbabdaaa";`
How can that string be checked out in efficient way finding the inside string duplicates:
I mean:

1. Looking for 2-letters string in `string`:

   **aa** = " **aa** bbcc **aa** abbcbbdbabd **aa** a";
   //NO whitespaces here or elsewhere in the `string`. Just added them to emphasize "aa".
   **aa** = "**aa** bbcca **aa** bbcbbdbabda **aa** ";
   total **aa** = 5;
   distance between **aa** = 4,5,11,12;

   **bb** = "aa **bb** ccaaa **bb** c **bb** dbabdaaa";
   total **bb** = 3;
   distance between **bb** = 5,1
   ...
2. Looking for 3-letters string in `string`:

   **aaa** = " **aaa** bbcc **aaa** bbcbbdbabd **aaa** ";
   total **aaa** = 3;
   distance between **aaa** = 4,10;
   ...

My attempt was in 4 cycles way and very slow.

**P.S.**
Any help is appreciated. Sorry for my English.


**EDIT:** 
Sorry for bad question. I've forgotten to say that the `string` should also be checked for 4 chars duplicates and other-chars duplicates:
**aabb** =  " **aabb** cca **aabb** cbbdbabdaaa";
total **aabb** = 2;
distance between **aabb** = 3;


**EDIT 2:** 
The duplicates we are looking for should not be entered manually. Imagine that the `string` is 20k symbols and you're searching for **ANY** duplicates (there no whitespaces) and the distance between those duplicates.
Thanks and sorry again for not correct question.

Comment: Which language? You have tagged as [tag:c#], [tag:php], [tag:javascript] …

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: if php you can checkout [substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

Comment: Any of that list. I prefer javascript, but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Josh, i know how does that code looks like. Only to answer your question (sorry, haven't read the link, to many text) http://pastebin.com/QpkUEm2q

Comment: Just to be clear, are we to assume that you have a set of known values to check for?  Or do you want a single algorithm that returns a list of all 2-character duplicates and their locations?

Comment: @SteveWortham, list of all [2, 3, ..., n/2] characters duplicates, where n = string length; (Not only 2-chars, but 3,4,etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution in C#

```
static Dictionary<string, List<int>> GetDuplicates2(string value)
{
    var duplicates = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int slength = 2; slength < (value.Length - i) / 2 + 2; slength++)
        {
            var littleString = value.Substring(i, slength);

            if (!duplicates.ContainsKey(littleString))
            {
                int nextOccurrence = value.IndexOf(littleString, i + slength - 1);

                if (nextOccurrence != -1)
                {
                    var l = new List<int>();
                    l.Add(i);
                    l.Add(nextOccurrence);
                    duplicates.Add(littleString, l);

                    while ((nextOccurrence = value.IndexOf(littleString, nextOccurrence + slength - 1)) != -1)
                    {
                        duplicates[littleString].Add(nextOccurrence);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return duplicates;
}
```

I wrote this according to your comment...

> list of all [2, 3, ..., n/2] characters duplicates, where n = string
>   length

I think this is working pretty well. It returns a Dictionary containing the string and the indices of each duplicate.  In terms of performance, calling `IndexOf()` so many times is probably the slowest part of this, but I don't know any way around that.

**UPDATE** 
I changed the code to include the overlapping requirement.

**UPDATE #2**
I added a couple conditions where the algorithm will `break` out of the inner `for` loop.  This improves performance quite a bit (especially when there are few duplicates to be found).

Comment: Your code returns aa=3 for input `aabbccaaabbcbbdbabdaaa`. it must be 5

Comment: @L.B. Ah, overlapping duplicates.  I didn't notice that requirement until you mentioned it.  I just updated the code to fix that.

Comment: I'm the only one who met the OP's requirement of finding ALL duplicates without searching for anything in particular.  And yet I get downvoted... nice.

Comment: Upvoted for you, Thank you :)
Gonna play around with my code for some time before choosing the 'most' correct answer if it can be called like that.

Comment: @SteveWortham I canceled my downvote but it won't be active unless you edit your answer.

Comment: @ted - My pleasure.  I was in the algorithm-writing mood today and your question seemed interesting so I gave it a try.

Answer (score 1):

There are many string search algorithms.

The wikipedia page summarizes them well:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript using normal string functions.

```
var a = " aa bbcc aa abbcbbdbabd aa a";
var s = "aa", ix = [], i=0; 
while(true){
    i = a.indexOf(s, i);
    if(i==-1)
       break;
    i += s.length
    ix.push(i);
}
```

Now `ix` contains the array of indexes where `s` (=`aa`) was found. `ix.length` is the number of total findings. And the following algorithm will find the differences in between.

```
var differences=[];
for(var j=1; j<ix.length; j++){
    differences.push(ix[j]-ix[j-1]);
}
```

This is faster alternative than Regular expression.

Comment: `s` should be: aa, ab, bb, bc, ... <br />
aab, abb, bbc, bcc, ... <br />
aabb, abbc, bbcc, ... <br />
etc. Sorry if you've misunderstood my question. I've edited it.

Comment: @ted Yeah, I know I show you how to do it. I didn't do it for you. You can loop through all the aa, bb, cc etc and get results from my codes.

Comment: Hmm. how can i loop through `a` so `s` = aa; (then: ab, bb,..aab, abb, ..aabb, abbc,..aabbccaaabb) then? Thank you. The code above is great (:

Answer (score 1):

This is almost exactly what the [LZW compression algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch) does, and it only requires a single pass through the string.

Comment: Excellent observation.  The overlapping duplicate requirements is perhaps the biggest difference.  Other than that, it is very similar.

Comment: By the way, I started to build a solution starting from an LZW implementation but ultimately I found too many differences.  In the end I think I was starting to rewrite my solution above.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript.

```
    onclick = "f('a',3)"  //return 2
    onclick = "f('a',2)"  //return 5
    .......
    var f = function(ch, nb){  //ch - searching character. nb - number of repetitions
       var str = "aabbccaaabbcbbdbabdaaa";
       var strLen = str.length;
       var res = 0;
       for(var i = 0; i < strLen; ++i){
          if(str[i] == ch){
             for(var j = i; j < nb+i || j <strLen; ++j){
                 if(str[j] != ch){
                 break;
                 }
                 if(j+1 == nb+i){
                 res++;
                 }
             }
          }
      }
    return res;
};
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear in my answer. The searching char and its number of repetitions should be entered manually as a sting can be 20k symblos, beside `aab`, `aas`, should be checked as well.